# Looping through linked records

Tags: c#

I am not sure if this is possible, but maybe someone could advise.

We have records set up in our system as follows:

```
Product_ID | Product_Name | Product_Price | Original_Product_ID
```

when a product is modified a new record is created with a reference to the previous encarnation in the `Original_Product_ID` field.

What I want to do is pass in a `Product_ID` (Current) and return the product which this came from, in some cases this will return the same as is passed in, in other cases I will need to loop through a number of records.

Please can someone advise on this...

Comment: is this done with a database or data classes and collections?

Comment: Are these records stored in a database or in memory? If they are in a database, what kind? You need to give more information about the domain of your problem.

Comment: and if the records are in a DBMS, which DBMS are you using?

Comment: "return the product which this came from" -> you mean a list of product ids or the very first one in the chain?

Comment: Your question suggests that there could be multiple direct ancestors for a current product - how could this be? Could you add some sample data?

Comment: The records are in an SQL database, gathered using Linq to SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need something like (non-recursive solution)?

```
Product GetOriginalProductById(int productId)
{
    Product p = GetProductById(productId);

    while (p.OriginalId != null && p.Id != p.OriginalId)
    {
        p = GetProductById(p.OriginalId);
    }

    return p;
}
```

Comment: This is looking more like what I was thinking, I will give it a try out and let you know how I come on. The only issue I can forsee would be in the cases where the p.OriginalId is NULL, i.e, that is the only entry for that product. Any suggestions on this one?

Comment: Added case for OriginalId == null.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple recursive approach:

```
void GetOriginalProducts(Item i, ref List<Item> items)
{
    if(i.ID == i.OriginalID) return;

    items.Add(i);
    GetOriginalProducts(items.Single(it => it.OriginalID == i.ID), ref items);
}
```